# Simplify pattern matching on type class instances with a certain member

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, typeclass, structural-typing

I have this framework that defines a type class with most instances having a certain implicit value:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

sealed trait Source

// many classes with implicit TypeTag
case class SourceA[T]()(implicit val ev: TypeTag[T]) extends Source
case class SourceB[T]()(implicit val ev: TypeTag[T]) extends Source
case class SourceC[T]()(implicit val ev: TypeTag[T]) extends Source
// a few classes without TypeTag
case class EmptySource() extends Source
```

In my app, I would like to access `ev` in the above example using simple code. Here's what I've come up with:

```
def retrieveTypeTagFromSource(source: Source): Option[TypeTag[_]] = source match {
  case s: SourceA[_] => Some(s.ev)
  case s: SourceB[_] => Some(s.ev)
  case s: SourceC[_] => Some(s.ev)
  // many more nearly identical lines
  // then handling the remaining classes
  case s: EmptySource => None
}
```

There are a lot of repetitions, not ideal. I would like to eliminate them without merely transferring the repetitions to the framework side (e.g. adding a `HasTypeTag` trait to every applicable case class). I tried using the following line when pattern matching:

```
case s: {val ev: TypeTag[Any]} => Some(s.ev)
```

but Scala warns `a pattern match on a refinement type is unchecked`, so I don't know if that actually works.

Comment: Side note: `TypeTag` is not available anymore with Scala 3. Depending on your context, you might want to start getting rid of it.

Comment: That isn't really a type class, you would need `Source` to be parameterised by type and have `implicit` instances for the supported types.

Answer (score 1):

Adding something like `HasTypeTag` does not have to be repetitious, just have two different `traits` and extend `TaggedSource` or `UntaggedSource` as appropriate.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

sealed trait Source
{
  def ott: Option[TypeTag[_]]
}

abstract class TaggedSource[T]()(implicit val tt: TypeTag[T]) extends Source {
  def ott = Some(tt)
}

trait UntaggedSource extends Source {
  def ott = None
}

// many classes with implicit TypeTag
case class SourceA[T]()(implicit val ev: TypeTag[T]) extends TaggedSource[T]
case class SourceB[T]()(implicit val ev: TypeTag[T]) extends TaggedSource[T]
case class SourceC[T]()(implicit val ev: TypeTag[T]) extends TaggedSource[T]
// a few classes without TypeTag
case class EmptySource() extends UntaggedSource

def retrieveTypeTagFromSource(source: Source): Option[TypeTag[_]] =
                  source.ott
```